# Oracle 11g count how many Mondays and Thursdays from a starting date until now

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In Oracle I would like to build a query that counts how many Mondays and Thursdays have gone by from a starting date counting both together.

For example:

from **20-MAY-18** to **today** (Thursday 31-MAY-18)

There has been the total count of 4 Mondays and Thursdays (2 Mondays and 2 Thursdays) have passed by from May 20 until today. I want to 4 in return in this query. If this query ran yesterday (Wednesday 30-MAY-18), I want to get 3 counts.

I am thinking subtracting the weeks from **today** minus **20-MAY-18**

Maybe something like this:

`select ( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( TO_DATE('20-MAY-18'), 'IW' ) ) / 7 * 2 from dual;`

I times it by two because of the monday and thursday. If the thurday hasn't come up yet then it gives the wrong result because of this week.

I cannot figure out to count the weekdays that have past this week to times it by the week count.

I need to be able also to change the days selected and not get stuck with only Monday and Thursday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help. You can add more logic to it. I'm not sure why this has to return 3 if ran on May 30th. What is he idea? Your start/end dates are the same and number of days between also the same no matter when you run it. What should happen if his run May 30?

```
WITH mon_thur AS
(
SELECT to_date('20-MAY-2018') + LEVEL-1 start_date
     , to_date('31-MAY-2018') end_date
     , to_date('31-MAY-2018') - to_date('20-MAY-2018') days_between
 FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= to_date('31-MAY-2018') - to_date('20-MAY-2018')+1  -- days_between+1
)
SELECT count(*) number_of_mon_thu FROM
(
SELECT start_date, to_char(start_date, 'D') d_date 
  FROM mon_thur
)
WHERE d_date IN (2, 4)
/
```

The output is 4. You can replace the 'D' format to 'DY' and replace 2, 4 with WHERE d_date IN ('MON', 'THU').

Comment: If it ran yesterday it should be 3 because Thursday hasn’t happened yet

Comment: If you look at the calendar and you count the Mondays and Thursdays from 20th to yesterday the 30th you'll see there's  3 because today will be the other Thursday.

Comment: @myhouse - Should your end date or days between be one day less then? If you remove my +1 in days between then this will give you correct result. Or you must determine this by day - Thursday?

Comment: Yes, let me run a few more test and I'll accept it. So far that worked. Yes I want to determine by today.

Comment: This does not work in all territories. [`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'DENMARK';`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/439) (or any territory where Sunday is not the first day of the week) and the code will not do what you expect. Also, it should be either `IN (1, 4)` or `IN (2,5)` since Thursday is 3 days after Monday (depending on whether Monday is day 1 or 2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to calculate the value:

Calculate the number of full days between the Monday of the week containing the start date and the Monday of this week:

```
( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) )
```

Divide it by 7 to get the number of full weeks:

```
 / 7
```

Multiply it by the number of days you want to match per week

```
* 2
```

Then adjust it to remove the Mondays and Thursdays that have been counted before the start date. This is 0 adjustment if the start day is Monday, 1 for Tuesday-Thursday and 2 for Friday-Sunday:

```
- DECODE( TRUNC( start_date ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ),
          0, 0, -- Monday
          1, 1, -- Tuesday
          2, 1, -- Wednesday
          3, 1, -- Thursday
          4, 2, -- Friday
          5, 2, -- Saturday
          6, 2  -- Sunday
        )
```

Then adjust it to include the days from the Monday of this current week to today:

```
+ DECODE( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ),
          0, 1, -- Monday
          1, 1, -- Tuesday
          2, 1, -- Wednesday
          3, 2, -- Thursday
          4, 2, -- Friday
          5, 2, -- Saturday
          6, 2  -- Sunday
        )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10e22/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( start_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2018-05-20' + LEVEL - 1
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY DATE '2018-05-20' + LEVEL - 1 <= SYSDATE;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT start_date,
       TO_CHAR( start_date, 'DY' ) As day,
       ( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) ) / 7 * 2
       - DECODE( TRUNC( start_date ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ),
                0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2 )
       + DECODE( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ),
                0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2 ) AS num_mon_and_thurs
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10e22/1/0)**:

```
|           START_DATE | DAY | NUM_MON_AND_THURS |
|----------------------|-----|-------------------|
| 2018-05-20T00:00:00Z | SUN |                 4 |
| 2018-05-21T00:00:00Z | MON |                 4 |
| 2018-05-22T00:00:00Z | TUE |                 3 |
| 2018-05-23T00:00:00Z | WED |                 3 |
| 2018-05-24T00:00:00Z | THU |                 3 |
| 2018-05-25T00:00:00Z | FRI |                 2 |
| 2018-05-26T00:00:00Z | SAT |                 2 |
| 2018-05-27T00:00:00Z | SUN |                 2 |
| 2018-05-28T00:00:00Z | MON |                 2 |
| 2018-05-29T00:00:00Z | TUE |                 1 |
| 2018-05-30T00:00:00Z | WED |                 1 |
| 2018-05-31T00:00:00Z | THU |                 1 |
```

> What if I want to change it instead of monday and thursday to be tuesday, wednesday, saturday? How do I do that?

```
SELECT start_date,
       TO_CHAR( start_date, 'DY' ) As day,
       ( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) ) / 7 * 3
       - DECODE( TRUNC( start_date ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ),
                0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3 )
       + DECODE( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ),
                0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 3 ) AS num_tue_wed_sat
FROM   table_name;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10e22/2)

Comment: Your formula works and I appreciate you doing that, but I cannot read it. I do not understand what you did.

Comment: What if I want to change it instead of monday and thursday to be tuesday, wednesday, saturday? How do I do that?

Comment: @myhouse Updated.